# Node.JS: How to transform nested callback in global function to be used later?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, scope

I have this tls client, inside this client I have a server which serves data from ServerX to PHP client... Insane, hu? Ok.. everything is working fine extremelly fast... But I want to answer the question from PHP as soon ServerX respond it, but its not Sync. Please, read:

```
var ServerX = tls.connect(port,host,options,function() {
    console.log(' Logging to ServerX...');
    var phpServer = dnode({
        fromPHP: function (variables,correlationalCallbackId,callBackToPHP) { // Shared PHP/NODE function
            othermodule.serialize(variable, function(buffer){ 
    HOW TO MAKE THIS-> global.phpCallBacks[correlationalCallbackId] = callBackToPHP; //I want to stores CallbackToPHP to use later when response from ServerX arrive
                ServerX.write(buffer,function(){ // write buffer to ServerX
                    //console.log("buffer sent");
                                    //callBackToPHP("Response from ServerX");//<--It works, but response dont exists
                });
                global.phpCallBacks[correlationalId]('Hi PHP! :)'); //Dont work even here
            });
        }// toNode END
    });
    //Starts DNODE server to integrate with PHP scripts
    phpServer.listen(PHPServerPort);    

});
```

And I want Call the callbackToPHP when receive especific response with correlational ID

```
ServerX.on('data', function(data) {
    othemodule.decode(data,function(message){ // message is an object with messageCorrelationId and other informations
        if(global.phpCallBacks[message.messageCorrelationId]) {
HOW TO MAKE IT WORK HERE-> global.phpCallBacks[message.messageCorrelationId](message.informations); // never fire :((
        }
    });
});
```

Hope its well explained... How to make CallBack function, when nested by milions of scopes, works in global scope?!?!?

Comment: I personally think [pillion](https://github.com/deoxxa/pillion) is better for RPC

Comment: Sorry, dont know what are you trying to say..